# How to judge the character and sign of a dislocation?

Tags: mathematics, material-science

[image]
I do understand that $ \mathbf b||\mathbf t$ for screw dislocation but I am unable to judge the sign of the dislocation. Again if $\mathbf b \perp \mathbf t$ how do I judge its sign? Any formula which explains the sign and magnitude (to some extent) will be highly appreciated. Here, $\mathbf{b}$ is the [Burger's vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers_vector) and $\mathbf{t}$ is the tangent vector.

Comment: +1 but can you tell us where you found this question? Is your $\mathbf{t}$ the "applied sheer stress" which is [often denoted as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation) $\mathbf{\tau}$?

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks.I found this question in GATE Metallurgical Engineering question papaer(which is precisely a competitive examination at the Undergrad level in India).$t$ is precisely the tangent vector.It has nothing to do with the applied shear stress.